# How can I find which games are available in the Microsoft PC Game Pass?

Tags: xbox-game-pass, xbox-game-pass-for-pc

Microsoft is offering its [PC game subscription service for $1](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-game-pass/pc-games).  Cool!  But, how can I determine which games are available on it?

- I found [this list](https://www.windowscentral.com/xbox-game-pass-pc-list), but it doesn't tell you anything about any of the games, and it won't be kept up-to-date.
- On the "Microsoft Store" Windows 10 app, you can click Games --> Browse all games, then filter by "Subscription Type: Game Pass".  However for some reason a lot of the games shown are console games, and not all of the PC Game Pass games are shown (ex. Into The Breach)
- The "XBox Console Companion" Windows 10 app has a Store --> Xbox Game Pass list, but it only shows the console Game Pass games, not the PC ones.

**Is there any way to view all the games on the PC Game Pass?**

Comment: Note: Game Pass is only $1 for the first month. Afterwards it's $5 a month.

Comment: @Nolonar: Well if you already own XBox Gold it's actually [$1 for up to 3 years](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/get-xbox-game-pass-for-up-to-3-years-at-no-extra-charge/), but that didn't seem important to mention in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on [xbox.com](https://www.xbox.com/en-us/xbox-game-pass/games), you can filter the games by Xbox Game Pass and then click PC games as shown in this screenshot below (marked the filter with yellow)

[image]

The whole thing is in beta anyway so expect the Windows Store and all related apps to be gradually updated. Till then you can use the site to check what games are available.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue when i got the Ultimate GamePass recently.

The thing to do is download the new Xbox(beta) app on your pc from the windows store.

Within the App you can see and download all the games for your pc.

Side Note: the App requires you to patch to the latest Win10 build, which forced me to install the Windows update before beieng able to use it.